# Adding new column in ms access table using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add a new column in `ms access` database table using a `Matlab` program.

I am search for a new column add query in Matlab.

The following code is not executing in script file.

```
exec(conn,'ALTER TABLE emp ALTER COLUMN (ZipCode Varchar)');
```

Comment: As i remember it must be Alter table emp add column (ZipCode Varchar)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
exec(conn,'ALTER TABLE emp ADD COLUMN ZipCode Varchar');
```